# One child at a time

Tags: nhibernate, insert, parent-child

Background:

- NHibernate 1.2
- C# 3.5 web application
- parent child association : A has a list of B
- Mapping is standard `<bag>`.

I can see, using NHProf and SQL Server profiler, that NHibernate sends one SQL insert for each B.

```
INSERT INTO B (a,b,c,d) VALUES (1,2,3,4);
INSERT INTO B (a,b,c,d) VALUES (4,5,6,7);
INSERT INTO B (a,b,c,d) VALUES (8,9,10,11);
```

How can I tell it to do:

```
INSERT INTO B (a,b,c,d) VALUES (1,2,3,4), (5,6,7,8), (9,10,11,12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer.

- set adonet.batch_size
- use HiLo generator for primary key instead of auto increment

I still see individual `INSERT`, but:

- less query count in SQL Server Profiler
- no more "SELECT scope_identity()" in NHProf